# YUI event listener for changes in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yui

```
/* listen for the submit button press */

YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(webserver.result_form, 'submit', webserver.result_submit);
```

I have this event listener in my `main.js`. Is there any way in YUI so I can listen a variable, so when this variable changes the event occurs. I was wondering if there is something like :

```
YAHOO.util."Variable".addListener(webserver.result_form, 'submit', webserver.result_submit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not directly assign listener to javascript variable but you can do it indirectly in following manner.

you can save the value of a variable in a div or any html node

e.g.

```
<div id="variable-name" style="display:none;">variable-value</div>
```

or

```
<span id="variable-name" style="display:none;">variable-value</span>
```

and then use following js to monitor any change in the node.
This will work in YUI3 or above. ( I am not sure about YUI2.x)

```
var Y = YUI().use('node', 'event', function (Y) {
    // node and event modules are loaded.
});    
var demo = Y.one('#variable-name');
    // And we can listen for DOM events.
        demo.on('change', function (e) {
            alert('value changed');
        });
```

for more info about listening for events to YUI node

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#listening-for-events

and lists of events available

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#event-whitelist

**EDIT**

based on http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html,

change event only fires if its form field

e.g. `input` `textarea` and `select`

so change event will not fire when contents of div is changed.

Comment: can you mark my reply as answer and upvote if its useful? thanks.

Comment: We did the following code but it still not working what is it missing ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268382/yui-modifying-and-detecting-changes-of-a-div